# How to remove a listener of an extension popup (React component), when the popup is closed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have an extension that was build with react (legacy code), and I have been tracking a bug that I have finally cornered, but I cannot fixed.

When the icon of the extension (in the browser bar) is clicked a react `Component` is created, and a listener is added in its `componentDidMount()`:

```
async componentDidMount(){
   ...
   // an object from the background is retrieved
   let background_object = this.props.getBackgroundObject();
   ...
   // code including await background_object.doSomething();
   ...
   // add event (eventemitter3 is used for the event management)
   background_object.event.on('onMusic', this.dance);
   ...
}

async dance() {
  this.setState({
    'music': true,
  })
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to remove the listener once the `Component` disappear, e.g. by clicking somewhere else in the browser. I thought that `componentWillUnmount` was what I looking for, but it is never called:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
  // this is never called!!!
  background_object.event.removeListener('onDance', this.dance);
}
```

The problem is that everytime I open (and close) the extension popup, a new event is added to the `background_object`, so that `dance()` is called multiple times (as many as I open and close the  popup).

For now, I have used `once` instead of `on`:

```
async componentDidMount(){
   ...
   // an object from the background is retrieved
   let background_object = this.props.getBackgroundObject();
   ...
   // code including await background_object.doSomething();
   ...
   // add event (eventemitter3 is used for the event management)
   background_object.event.once('onMusic', this.dance);
   ...
}

async dance() {
 // add the event again in case onMusic is called again
 background_object.event.once('onMusic', this.dance);
 this.setState({
   'music': true,
 })
}
```

In this way, at least, it's only called once. However, I am concerned that **my component is being created multiple times** and consuming memory in my browser.

How can I make sure that the component is actually being destroyed? How can I detect when the popup is closed in order to remove the event?

Comment: why are the functions async? I think the problem could be related to this. componentWillUnmount should be called. Your approach with removing listener on unmount is correct.

Comment: The popup is terminated immediately so no unload code will run. Use a dummy port connection in the background script instead, [more info](/a/15801294), [example](/a/39756934).

Comment: @oshell, it is an async, because there is some await functions in the `...` parts. I read about this, and it is normal (as I said, this is legacy code, so cannot five you a full answer)

Comment: @wOxxOm, that seems like a solution (sort of makes sense, except I was expecting something more graceful from React). I will try in a few hours, and post about the result. What is the `componentWillUnmount` for then? Maybe it just does not work for extensions?

Comment: The popup is terminated immediately so no unload/unmount code will run.

Comment: try not making the function async and put the async logic you want in there in a self executing async function. at least the componentWillUnmount should be triggered

Comment: @wOxxOm, that did not work. Ehe event triggers when `runtime.connect` is called, which i cannot find anywhere in the code.

Comment: oh, wait, i see, that is exactly the point. I need to connect, and when the popup is terminated, the connection will die. That is a bit hackish, but will do. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use `chrome.runtime.onConnect` for this (thanks @wOxxOm):

1. In the constructor of the React component open a connection:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dance: false,
    }
    ...
    var port = this.xbrowser.runtime.connect();
    ...
  }
```

2. Add the event in `componentDidMount` of the react Component.

```
async componentDidMount(){
   ...
   // an object from the background is retrieved
   let background_object = this.props.getBackgroundObject();

   ...
   // add event (eventemitter3 is used for the event management)
   background_object.event.on('onMusic', this.dance);
   ...
}

async dance() {
  this.setState({
    'music': true,
  })
}
```

3. Somewhere in the background (e.g `background.js`) listen to the connections to the browser, and remove the event when the connection is lost:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (externalPort) {
  externalPort.onDisconnect.addListener(function () {
     let background_object = this.props.getBackgroundObject();
     background_object.event.removeListener('onSend'); 
  })
})
```

In my head, this is not very elegant, but it is doing the trick.