# not able to remove browser extension in my select field

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have below `react-select` componet. it works as `searchable dropdown` .

```
 <div className='input'>
  <Select 
        id="sponsor" 
        name="sponsor"
        className={styles.input}
        placeholder="Sponsor"
        options={result.map((sponsor:Sponsor)=>
              ({ label: sponsor.name, value: sponsor.id })
      )}
  })
}}
/>
</div>
```

the red part is browser extension which is coming. I can not remove it bcoz of org policy.

[image]

when I type text to serach in select it comes like below.

[image]

I am not able to remove it I tried my best. below is content of my `scss` file.

```
Select{
    text-shadow: none;
    background-image: none;
    background: none!important;
}
 input {
    padding: .5rem;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: none !important;
    background-image: none;
    
  }
```

basically its an image. when I inspect it it comes like this.
[image]

if I mark image as hidden in browser inspection ,this goes off. how can I make changes in my `scss` file or component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a listener of an extension popup (React component), when the popup is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802145/how-to-remove-a-listener-of-an-extension-popup-react-component-when-the-popup)

Comment: actually its regarding css issue. If I remove extension for chrome, for other broswer issue will be there.

Comment: Try closing the `select` element and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: its already close in file. by mistake I did not copy completed. is there anything to put image off in input field?

Comment: If the `id` for this image is never changing, you can try to suppress it in CSS by this using selector:  `#__lpform_react-select-3-input_icon { display: none; }` or something similar.

Comment: thank you. image id is same but its not working.

Comment: I am writing this in scss file and then in my page I am writing <div id="__lpform_react-select-3-input_icon"> <Select tag></div> .its still not working